# Parent Child component object transfer in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({  
 getInitialState: function () {
   return { items: '' };
},

componentDidMount: function () {

    this.onSuccess();

},

onSuccess: function () {

  this.setState({ items: items });
 },

 render: function () {

  return (

          <Cart items={this.state.items} >
            <CartHeader />
            <CartContent />
            <CartFooter />
          </Cart>
   )   
  }
 });


window.Cart = React.createClass({

render: function () {

return (

      <div>
        Cart{this.props.children}

      </div>  

  );
 }
 });



window.CartHeader = React.createClass({

render: function () {
return (

      <div>
        CartHeader
        {this.props.items}
     </div>  

   );
 }
 });



 window.CartContent = React.createClass({

render: function () {
return (

      <div>
            CartContent
            {this.props.items}
        </div>  

  );
  }
 });



 window.CartFooter = React.createClass({

render: function () {
return (

      <div>
        CartFooter
        {this.props.items}
        </div>  

  );
  }
 });
```

Where "items" is an object.

Now, my question is how to get the value of object in child?

Is it proper way to do? Actually, I am new to this.
If any suggestion, please let me know.

My purpose is to send object data to each child, so that in future if I don't want to "cartHeader", I can remove the component from that.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways you can do:

```
1. <Cart items={this.state.items} >
    Under Cart component load the child component and pass the this.props.item in each child.

2. Use Context

3. Use cloneElement function
```

I prefer 2 option in this case(scenario)

Comment: you should avoid using context when you have other options, more info about it https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html